# Double post issue in angular 4

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api

Web API is running in IIS. and I'm using CLI to run the angular project. Http post hitting Web API method twice.
First-time web API parameter is going as null. And second time with a parameter.

API

```
 [System.Web.Http.Route("api/Location/AddNewLocationSection")]
 [HttpPost]
 [AcceptVerbs("OPTIONS")]
 public GenericResult AddNewCustomerLocationSection(GenericParam<CustomerLocationSectionTreeItem> locationSectionParam)
 {
   //due to double post i'm doing this check
   if (locationSectionParam != null && locationSectionParam.Parameter != null)
   {
      //logic
   }
 }
```

Angular service

```
addNewLocationSection(locationSectionDetails: CustomerLocationSectionInfo): Observable<any> {
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post(this._configuration.AddNewLocation JSON.stringify({ parameter: locationSectionDetails }), new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }))
.map(this.extractData)
.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Component

```
this.locationDetailService.addNewLocationSection(this.locationSectionDetails)
.subscribe(success => this.reLoadCustomerLocationTree(success, "Add"),
error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

How I can avoid this double post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the first call, it is an OPTIONS request. It's a request send by browsers to check the validity of an endpoint. I don't think you can change it !

[You can find more information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)

Comment: so it means using OPTIONS I can't stop this?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think